# Snowflake session no longer exists. new login required to access the service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, .net-core-3.1

I am pulling data from Snowflake into my .NET MVC 3.1 application using Snowflake .NET connector(Snowflake.Data) and running into an issue as below:

The issue occurs only when there is no call from app to Snowflake for more than 4 hours.

"Session no longer exists. New login required to access the service. SqlState: , VendorCode: 390111"

I understand this can be fixed by setting CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=True which I guess is not supported by .NET ? Is there any workaround?

```
public async Task<List<PO>> FetchPO(string plant)
{
    using IDbConnection dbConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection();
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(Constants.ConnectionStrings.SnowflakeConnectionString);

    List<PO> po= (await dbConnection.QueryAsync<PO>($"select * from {Constants.Snowflake.Views.PO} ")).ToList();

    return po;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the .NET driver doesn't supports CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE as you mentioned.

One way for keeping the session alive would be to send a simple query before the session expires (by default when no activity the session expires after 4 hours), like a `SELECT 1`. But be aware if you have many clients using this it may impact your Cloud Services [billing](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#cloud-services-credit-usage).

As for CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE in .NET you can create an [Idea](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Search-Create-Vote-Follow-Ideas) for this and the more customers need it the more chances to get it implemented.

Comment: Do you recommend to run a query every hour or so, like a trigger? I do not think web app is supposed to do that

Comment: Can I do this outside of web app? Like a separate scheduler to hit snowflake using same user account?

Comment: Outside of web app you will have most probably a different session, so that would not work. Yes, every hour like a trigger, and indeed is not the most elegant way for the web app but it is one way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. I will explore this way